# How to put value from 3 set of arrays into differences div in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, arrays

Supposing I have 3 divs. ANd I have 3 sets of array. I need to put the values in each array into those 3 divs. I wonder how to do ?

Let´s se my example divs.

```
<div id='001'><div id="nr001"><div id="clr001"></div></div></div>
<div id='002'><div id="nr002"><div id="clr002"></div></div></div>
<div id='003'><div id="nr003"><div id="clr003"></div></div></div>
```

And I have 3 sets of array like this (Maybe I have more but now let example with 3 sets):

```
**These array are from JSON.parse();**

[["001", "002", "003"],["8", "9", "20"], [ "brown", "black", "yellow"]]
```

**What I want to do:**
I want to put those values in arrays into the correct id div, it must be like this:

```
<div id='001'>8<div id="nr001"><div id="clr001">brown</div></div></div>
<div id='002'>9<div id="nr002"><div id="clr002">black</div></div></div>
<div id='003'>20<div id="nr003"><div id="clr003">yellow</div></div></div>
```

What I have tried is :

```
var str = xmlHttp.responseText;
var res = JSON.parse(str);

var set1 = res[0], set2 = res[1], set3 = res[3];
for (var i = 0; i < set1.length; i++) {
    var div1 =  document.getElementById("nr"+set1[i]);
    var div2 =  document.getElementById("clr"+set1[i]);
    if (div1) {
        div1.innerHTML = set2[i];     
    }

  if (div2) {
        div2.innerHTML = set3[i];     

    }
}
```

I got only div2 but not div1. I guess I need more lines of script. Or new method :S

**UPDATE AFTER GET THE SOLUTION:**

I have to say thanks for everyone that gave me solution. everyone is correct, it´s my fault that I did not explian all details that I use setTimeout() to recall function every 15 second. So other answer are kind of append the element ? When another call finished the result append to the old result+++++

But After I assign the span instead of ussing div both. So the problem is gone. I got message like I want. Thanks for everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your divs are nested, you cannot simply assign `innerHTML` of the outer div - that will destroy its content. You'll need an extra tag to put the text in:

```
<div id='001'><span id="xyz001"></span><div id="nr001"><div id="clr001"></div></div></div>

var span =  document.getElementById("xyz"+set1[i]);
var div2 =  document.getElementById("clr"+set1[i]);
if (span) {
    span.innerHTML = set2[i];     
}

if (div2) {
    div2.innerHTML = set3[i];     
}
```

Comment: Hi, I would love to do as you said, But div nr#2 i need to assign the possition absolute to it. So I can not use the span tag.

Comment: Well, your solution is the best. Although I have to change my design alittle bit but it save my time to be crazy like this. Thank s

Answer (score 0):

```
var res = [["001", "002", "003"], ["8", "9", "20"], [ "brown", "black", "yellow"]];

for (var i = res[0].length - 1; i > -1; i--)
{
    var suffix = res[0][i];
    var container = document.getElementById(suffix);
    var div1 = document.getElementById("nr" + suffix);
    var div2 = document.getElementById("clr" + suffix);

    container.insertBefore(document.createTextNode(res[1][i]), div1);
    div2.innerHTML = res[2][i];
}
```

Comment: It may be because you forgot to close one of the `<div>` tags.

Comment: I´m soory for my mistake, I have update the question , Please see the Divs again. the last div is inside the second. Do you think this is the problem ? or doeasn´t matter ?

Comment: Hello I have tried it now many times. Yes I got both 2 values but the div change positon :S

Comment: ANother problem I can see is the div clr. starting to increase value every 15 seconds. I forgot to say that i use setTimeout() to recall function every 15 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Just modified Omer Hassan answer. You have to append data to main div with its innerHTML and then append data to inner div like:

```
var res = [["001", "002", "003"],["8", "9", "20"], [ "brown", "black", "yellow"]];

for (var i = res[0].length - 1; i > -1; i--)
{
    var suffix = res[0][i];
    var div1 =  document.getElementById("nr" + suffix);


    div1.innerHTML = res[1][i] + div1.innerHTML;   

    var div2 =  document.getElementById("clr" + suffix);
    div2.innerHTML = res[2][i];
}
```

<kbd>**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nLw8e/)**</kbd>

Comment: I would love to try this, but the data did not come in this form. I mean I don´t have the word res in front of my array.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
var data = [["001", "002", "003"],["8", "9", "20"], ["brown", "black", "yellow"]];

for ( var i = 0; i < data[0].length; i++ ) {
    var div1 = document.getElementById(data[0][i]);
    div1.innerHTML = data[1][i] + div1.innerHTML;
    document.getElementById('clr' + data[0][i]).innerHTML = data[2][i];  
}
```

BTW, I assume that the first array is the `ID`s, so I just loop through them. That's why you see `data[0].length`.

Live @ [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a7s93/1/) and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/h6ybV/1/) again.

Comment: Hi JSFiddle I would love to try yours but my data does not come in this form. I have no idea how. COuld you please change the data as I have set in my question ? I mean I don´t have the word data in front of my aray.

Comment: @PoramatFin well, I really didn't get it. I just added some CSS classes, should I remove them? that's just for demonstration ... the DOM and data structure is absolutely same as what you have up there ...

Comment: You don´t need to remove, because it can be use for other. I appreciate every answers. I want to keep it ! Maybe i use in some other case.

Comment: @PoramatFin BTW, I meant removing the `CSS Classes` not the answer! :)

Comment: Ahh sorry I misunderstand.Mahdi
I can see your demo is work but as I said my data did not come in this from. To use your script I need to change the way to send the data from php. I use json_encode() to send those arrays from php. <<<and they´re comming from database with separate query.

Comment: @PoramatFin well, then good luck with that ... my answer works with the data that you provided here, if the data is different in your side, then I hope you come with a solution soon. :)

Comment: Please do not delet you answer, as I said it can be used latter. I maybe have to change the way to send data from php. I will check on it latter.



But i see that it´s hard to change as long as this function will affect the other function that concern.

Comment: @PoramatFin oh, no worries, i'm not gonna delete it. :)